# Hadith about Allah commanding angels to destroy a pious man

Tags: hadith, reference-request

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers,

There is a famous "Weak" Hadith about how Allah commanded the angels to destroy a town but the angels told Allah that there was an obedient pious slave of His in there. So Allah commanded the Angels to destroy him as well because he didn't forbid evil and enjoin good.

I have heard from many that this hadith is very weak. 
But I don't have a written reference of it being weakened.

Can you please provide me a source which states that this hadith is weak?

Answer (score 1):

Wa Alaikum As Salam.

As per Imam Bayhaqi رحمه الله, this isn't a statement of the Prophet (ﷺ).

A few references:

- [Islamweb](https://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/PrintFatwa.php?lang=E&Id=177275)
- [Hadith Answers](https://hadithanswers.com/punishment-for-not-forbidding-evil-2/)